# Is there a size limit on a CRX for a Chrome app that's installed manually?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm distributing a chrome app internally at our company and due to spec changes, it will need to include 500MB of files. Will Chrome allow that to be installed? Is there a size restriction?

(This is an App, not an Extension)

Comment: A [chromium-extensions group post from 2012](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/kbSwtA9cvOU) says probably not. (There's also [one from 2010](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/E2xNejeem6s), but it is less helpful.)

Comment: @apsillers Hmmm...why is it so hard to get documentation and definitive answers from the Google Chrome/Chromium group?

Comment: I think this should be easy enough to test yourself -- just make a Chrome extension that has a video, ISO disc image, VM drive, or other big file. If you do, feel free to answer your own question, and the Internet will be richer for finally having a definitive answer. :)

Comment: @apsillers Yes, I could test it myself but that would be possibly "dangerous". Since this is undocumented, they could change it at any time. If I program for something 100MB in size and then they (silently) change it to 50MB my app will fail. We need a documented amount from the Chromium/Chrome team.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, There is a limit of 2 GB while this answer is being posted.

Here is a link for ref.

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/faq#apps

Comment: if you can post a source, I'll mark this as the answer

Comment: Don, this is the correct answer. Mark this as answer to close this up.

Comment: Just note that this 2GB limit is for webstore.. I would guess that .crx file doesnt have any limits. and for your case Don, its only around 500MB, so you should be fine.

Comment: @fedmich I'm not marking this as an answer since that's the size specified for the webstore, and my question is about a manually installed app. There's no guarantee that the manual one will have a larger limit, it could be the opposite but this is undocumented.

Answer (score 1):

I think not. Google Chromium is not just trying to be a browser or OS for specific devices, its trying to be a platform. See this link from GigaOM:
http://gigaom.com/2013/05/22/how-google-plans-to-rule-the-computing-world-through-chrome/

From the article:
"A good example of a native client app is a game I played on my Chromebook Pixel recently called Cracking Sands Racing The app, a port of a game for iOS and Android, was a **533 MB download** to my Pixel and I played it outside of the browser."

Now mind you that this is a packaged app and not extension per say (see the difference here: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html). But I would think that you should be able to create bigger extension without much problem. As others have said, a sure way would be to create a dummy huge file and packaging it in your extension.

Just my 2 cents, even though it does not answer your question fully.